# Terminal display become weird sometime

Tags: release-juno, pantheon-terminal, release-hera

i'm using Elementary OS Hera (was Juno before). Every time my laptop wake up from sleep mode and my current opened terminal display become weird.

Before sleep mode:
[image: A normal terminal display]

After sleep mode:
[image: Werid terminal after wake up from sleep mode]

I also notice that sometime it become like that even though i didn't sleep mode my laptop. Do we have any solution for this?

I'm using Laptop MSI GL62M 7RDX Nvidia GTX 1050

Comment: Do you have the same issue when you use the standalone Terminal application or is this limited to the terminal embedded in VSC?

Comment: Ok i think the weird display issue is only in VSC terminal.

Comment: I am a VSC user and I have not been able to reproduce this issue. Did you install VSC as a flatpak or from a .deb file? I am using the Flatpak version, perhaps you can try it if you used a .deb.